# Muss „als solche“ in diesem Satz gebeugt werden?

Tags: grammar, adjective-ending, inflection

Der Satz

> Das Wissen wird dazu verwendet, die Wahrscheinlichkeit von fälschlicherweise erkannten Maxima zu verringern.

ist grammatikalisch sicher richtig. Ich möchte aber Folgendes sagen:

> Das Wissen wird dazu verwendet, die Wahrscheinlichkeit von fälschlicherweise als solche erkannten Maxima zu verringern.

Ich bin mir hier unsicher, ob *als solche* gebeugt werden muss, ob es also korrekterweise

> Das Wissen wird dazu verwendet, die Wahrscheinlichkeit von fälschlicherweise als solche**n** erkannten Maxima zu verringern.

heißen müsste. Mein Sprachgefühl verlässt mich hier. Für mich klingen beide Varianten nicht ganz richtig, eine davon muss aber korrekt sein. Welche?

Comment: Ich habe meine Antwort mal zurückgezogen, weil sie nicht ganz richtig war. Interessant könnte das hier sein: http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Konjunktion/Gebrauch/Satzteil.html#Anchor-Bezug-35882

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also ich würde mir das folgendermaßen herleiten:

> Das Wissen wird dazu verwendet, *wen* von *wem* zu verringern.

Dann kommen wir zu

> Das Wissen wird dazu verwendet, die Wahrscheinlichkeit von fälschlicherweise als *wer oder was* erkannten Maxima zu verringern.

Maxima wurden fälschlicherweise als Maxima erkannt, also haben wir hier einen Nominativ Plural.

> Das Wissen wird dazu verwendet, die Wahrscheinlichkeit von fälschlicherweise als Maxima erkannten Maxima zu verringern.

Und die Ersetzung wegen Doppelung von *Maxima* wäre dann

> Das Wissen wird dazu verwendet, die Wahrscheinlichkeit von fälschlicherweise als solche/diese/jene erkannten Maxima zu verringern.

Geht auch ohne *von* und dann mit Genitiv. Das klingt meiner Meinung nach auch besser:

> Das Wissen wird dazu verwendet, die Wahrscheinlichkeit fälschlicherweise als solche erkannter Maxima zu verringern.

Da die Aussage des Satzes jedoch ist, dass es eine Wahrscheinlichkeit gibt, dass ein Maximum doch gar kein Maximum ist, würde ich das gegebenenfalls umformulieren und sagen:

> Das Wissen wird dazu verwendet, die Wahrschenlichkeit fälschlicherweise als Maxima erkannter Punkte/Werte zu verringern.